# AJAX sending data to laravel controller and it is not working

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to send user slug to my laravel controller and its not working
here is my html code :

```
<a class="card" onclick="chat_send($data = '{{$user->slug}}');">
```

here is my script :

```
function chat_send(){
    var data = $data;
    var action_url = '{{ route('chat.show','data')}}';
                            
     $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url : action_url,
          data : {data:data},
          dataType : "json",
          success:function(data){
              if(data.errors){
                  alert('Message Field is Empty.');

          }
          if(data.success){
            alert('Success');

          }
       }
    });
 };
```

controller code :

```
public function show(Request $request)
    {
        $slug = $request->get('data');
        

        return view('chat',compact('slug'));
        // return view('test');

    }
```

this is the error I got :
[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gbkvy.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO ... do you know JavaScript ?

Comment: data should pass like this in ajax

data : {data:data}

and in Laravel controller catch as post

Comment: no  i dont know JS i just started learning

Comment: i edited the data to {data:data} still not working

Answer (score 1):

Just do this error will be resolved.

```
<a class="card" onclick="chat_send('{{$user->slug}}');">
```

And in script:

```
function chat_send(data){                          
      var action_url = '{{ route('chat.show','data')}}';                            
      $.ajax({
           type : "POST",
           url : action_url,
           data : {data:data},
           dataType : "json",
           success:function(data){
                if(data.errors){
                   alert('Message Field is Empty.');

                }
                if(data.success){
                    alert('Success');


                }
          }
     });
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below:

```
<a class="card" id="card" data = '{{$user->slug}}'>
```

Use JQuery for sending ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#card').click(function(){
          var data = $(this).attr(data)
          var action_url = '{{ route('chat.show','data')}}';
                        
          $.ajax({
               type : "POST",
               url : action_url,
               data : {data:data},
               dataType : "json",
               success:function(data){
                  if(data.errors){
                     alert('Message Field is Empty.');

                  }
                  if(data.success){
                       alert('Success');

                   }
                }
           });
        };
      })
      
})
```